# How do you Reset a While Loop without Breaking it in Java?

Tags: java, validation, while-loop

I'm a Begginer to Java and I'm trying to use JOptionPanes to input my Variables.
Whilst Trying to validate my input Variables I put the input statements in this while loop.

```
while (input==false)
{
    inputNumberCoeffa=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter co-efficient of X: ");
    inputNumberConsta=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Constant Number: ");
    inputNumberPowa=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Power Bracket should be raised to:");
    if (inputNumberCoeffa==null
        || inputNumberConsta==null
        || inputNumberPowa==null
        ||inputNumberCoeffa.isEmpty()
        || inputNumberConsta.isEmpty()
        || inputNumberPowa.isEmpty()
        || inputNumberCoeffa.matches("[A-Za-z]*")
        || inputNumberConsta.matches("[A-Za-z]*")
        || inputNumberPowa.matches("[A-Za-z]*"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter a Number");        
    }
    else 
    {
        input=true;
    }
    double inputNumberCoeff=Double.parseDouble(inputNumberCoeffa);
    double inputNumberConst=Double.parseDouble(inputNumberConsta);
    double inputNumberPow=Double.parseDouble(inputNumberPowa);
}
```

This while loop was made to protect the parseDouble Statements at the Bottom from bad data. However to display the error message you have to enter in each point of Data. I could put a While loop around each Data entry point but I would Like to know is there a more efficient way that this question can be resolved?

Comment: where is the end of your while loop? you might want to edit your post

Comment: put whole thing in another while block. this could be reset condition or continue condition when inner while exits

Comment: it is not clear if your problem is breaking the loop or avoid to use three times the same loop for the three variables you want to set. you might want to edit your code and rephrase your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Dialog Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Something that you can do is create a class that validates input and implement [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) and then create `JOptionPane`s and call `addKeyListener()` and pass it your listener. So as the user types things into your JOptionPane, you can filter what is being typed (and set the property as "0" or something if they hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> without typing anything). You can also add additional listeners (see also: [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)) if you need other events to be handled.

Comment: While Silli's approach does work, this one is more clean in terms of usability and what the user would expect to happen.

Answer (score 1):

create a method that returns a double and contains the while loop plus all the required checks plus the parse double statement and use that to set your inputNumberXXX variables. In this way you won't have to copy and paste the code three times because you will just invoke three times the same method.